# Apple Wireless Might Mouse keeps disconnecting?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have an Apple Wireless Mighty Mouse (*not* the newer Magic Mouse) that I've used for a couple of years.

In recent months, though, the mouse would spontaneously disconnection itself at random, even when the batteries are still full.

Does anyone have experience with this or know how to fix it?

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8 if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try completely disconnecting the mouse from your computer, then re-pairing the mouse with the computer. I don't know if that'll help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried to remove the mouse from Bluetooth preferences, turned Bluetooth off then back on, and restarting my Mighty Mouse. Now the Bluetooth Setup Assistant can see the mouse but can't pair with it!

Comment: You have replaced the batteries, right?

Comment: Yes I sure did. :)

Comment: Just makin' sure. :-)

Comment: I'll look into it more. I am working right now, but I'll work on it this evenin'

Comment: @penyuan I am at a loss as to what to do. I have no idea!!! So sorry I can't help!!